# Authorize calls to API based on Client Id

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I have a C# API that uses IdentityServer3 to authorize calls to the methods.

I want to limit which calls a certain client can access. The client is using the Client Credentials flow and I’m trying to find a way to authorize calls based on the client id.

Is there a way to do this out of the box, or will I need to write a custom filter?

Comment: try this one OAuth 2 - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: Thanks, but that link is not much help. I have the client credential flow working, but I need a way to restrict the methods that can be called.

Comment: One solution is.. Register all client id and limit the access of it.. In your API itself.

Comment: @reds yes, that’s what I’ll be doing, but I’m asking if there’s a way to do this with an Authorize attribute, or if I need to write a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding an authentication manager - if you look at the Identity Server samples such as the "MVC Authentication" one, this registers a custom authentication manger in the startup and then uses nice simple resource attributes to protect each Controller action.

e.g. This goes in your startup

```
app.UseResourceAuthorization(new AuthorizationManager());
```

Then define your custom Auth manager class, like....

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ResourceAuthorizationManager
{
    public override Task<bool> CheckAccessAsync(ResourceAuthorizationContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Resource.First().Value)
        {
            case "PageAuthCheck":
                return AuthorizeContactDetails(context);
            default:
                return Nok();
        }
    }

    private Task<bool> AuthorizeContactDetails(ResourceAuthorizationContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Action.First().Value)
        {
            case "Read":
                return Eval(context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
            case "Write":
                return Eval(context.Principal.HasClaim("role", "Admin"));
            default:
                return Nok();
        }
    }
}
```

After which you can protect your controller actions simply like....

```
    [ResourceAuthorize("Read", "PageAuthCheck")]
```

Obviously this is just an example that is using a user claim role check, but you should be able to easily change this to protect based on client id

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a clientid and a clientSecret. You just need to implement a logic that will check if your clientid and clientSecret is valid to access your app.

check this sample and update it based on your need

```
   public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {

        string clientId = string.Empty;
        string clientSecret = string.Empty;
        Client client = null;

        if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
        {
            context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
        }

        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            //Remove the comments from the below line context.SetError, and invalidate context 
            //if you want to force sending clientId/secrects once obtain access tokens. 
            context.Validated();
            //context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "ClientId should be sent.");
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            client = _repo.FindClient(context.ClientId);
        }

        if (client == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_clientId", string.Format("Client '{0}' is not registered in the system.", context.ClientId));
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        if (client.ApplicationType == Models.ApplicationTypes.NativeConfidential)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client secret should be sent.");
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (client.Secret != Helper.GetHash(clientSecret))
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client secret is invalid.");
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!client.Active)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client is inactive.");
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin", client.AllowedOrigin);
        context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime", client.RefreshTokenLifeTime.ToString());

        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

you can also check this tutorial [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/)